# Why is it saying the property of show is undefined?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a nodecg bundle similar to:https://github.com/Chr12t0pher/vespyr-nodecg
I currently have it hosted here: https://github.com/SilverStateEsports/lolStream
Im not quite sure what the problem is and while googleing part of the stack trace, it came up with broser support being deprecated, but that did not seem to be the problem.

code:

```
var concat = require("concat-stream");
var hyperquest = require('hyperquest');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var URL = 'http://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls';
var HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'node-strawpoll'
};

function create(options) {
    var stream = hyperquest.post(URL, {headers: HEADERS});
    stream.end(querystring.stringify(options));
    return stream;
}

function get(id) {
    var stream = hyperquest.get(URL + '/' + id);
    return stream;
}

module.exports = function(nodecg) {
    var strawpollReplicant = nodecg.Replicant("strawpoll",
        {defaultValue: {"id": "", "options": ["", ""], "result": [0,0], "show": false, "time": 0}}
    );

    nodecg.listenFor("strawpoll-create", function(data) {
        var stream = create({
            title: "Who will win?",
            options: data,
            multi: false,
            permissive: true
        });

        stream.pipe(concat(function(poll) {
            poll = JSON.parse(poll);
            strawpollReplicant.value = {"id": poll.id, "options": data, "result": [0, 0], "show": false, "time": 0};
        }));
    });

    strawpollReplicant.on("change", function(oldVal, newVal) {
        if (newVal["show"]) {
            if (newVal["time"] <= 600) { // Update for 10 minutes max.
                var stream = get(newVal["id"])
                    .pipe(concat(function(poll) {
                        poll = JSON.parse(poll);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            newVal["time"] += 3;
                            newVal["result"] = poll["votes"];
                            strawpollReplicant.value = newVal;
                        }, 3000);
                    }));
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Stack trace:

```
 warn: [nodecg/lib/server/extensions] Failed to mount sse-lol-stream extension:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\bundles\sse-lol-stream\extension\strawpoll.js:42:13
    at Replicant.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\lib\replicant\replicant.js:167:5)
    at Replicant.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Replicant.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at _addListener (events.js:353:14)
    at Replicant.addListener (events.js:401:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\bundles\sse-lol-stream\extension\strawpoll.js:41:24)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\bundles\sse-lol-stream\extension\index.js:5:30)
    at _loadExtension (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\lib\server\extensions.js:103:37)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.init (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\lib\server\extensions.js:32:6)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.start (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\lib\server\index.js:310:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ethan\Desktop\lolStream\nodecg\index.js:77:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodecg-cli\dist\commands\start.js:11:13)
    at Command.listener (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodecg-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodecg-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodecg-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodecg-cli\dist\index.js:37:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodecg-cli\dist\bin\nodecg.js:22:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting a `change` event where `newVal` is undefined:

```
    strawpollReplicant.on("change", function(oldVal, newVal) {
        if (newVal["show"]) {
```

I'd make sure that `newVal` is actually defined.   I haven't used nodecg so I don't have further ideas.